# How to set asynchronous loop to query data in Apache IoTDB using M4 calculation?

Tags: database, performance, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When using M4 calculation in Apache IoTDB, currently only can query data in one measuring point. Therefore, when I need to query multiple measuring points using M4, it is necessary to do a circular query. When there are more than 10 measuring points that need to be query, the speed is a bit slow ( about 1~2 seconds late), so I used an asynchronous loop to query. However, an error that reported null pointer would appear: "executeStatement failed
org.apache.iotdb.commons.exception.IoTDBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException". Anyone know how to reset the query method to avoid reporting this error?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please